# How to do href in php

Tags: php, html, mysql, href

At the beginning I would like to say that this is my first post and I apologize in advance for any possible mistakes. And these are my beginnings in programming.

I have a problem with appropriate action download.php in the following code snippet:

```
<?php
    $cv= $row[25];
    $output .= ' 
    <tr>
        <td> <a href='download.php?dow=$cv'>Download</a> </td> 
    </tr> 
    ';  
?>
```

I wish it worked like the following code (in which it operates correctly):

```
<tr>
    <td><?php   echo "<a href='download.php?dow=$cv'>Download</a><br>"; ?></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between single-quoted and double-quoted strings in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446216/what-is-the-difference-between-single-quoted-and-double-quoted-strings-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

You need to concatenate the string. To concatenate you use a dot `.` This will put the variable value inside your string.

```
<?php

$output .= " 
<tr>
     <td><a href='download.php?dow=".$cv."'>Download</a> </td> 
</tr> 
";
```

Comment: To help the OP understand the issue, you should explain what you have changed and why. Don't just paste some code.

Comment: Thank you very much for the apposition, but still pops up an error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'download' (T_STRING)

Comment: @kejt You need to look at the quotes in this answer compared to yours. Specifically the usage of single and double quotes. This is one of the reasons why a good answer includes a full explanation about  the changes and the original issue.

Comment: there is no need to write variable outside `"` unlike the `'`.

Comment: Yes it's true. No longer causes a fatal error. But I would like to ask why after clicking on the Download downloaded file "download.php" (which is empty) instead of "something.docx" (as is the case with the correct link)

Comment: I don't really understand your question. Do you get a downloaded file called "download.php"?

Answer (score 0):

you closed string before it's even finished!
the `$output` is a variable and you tried to store the HTML as an string inside it, but you've closed the `'` sign before the  `download.php?dow=$cv` and then opened it again. the correct way to write it is:

```
<?php
$cv= $row[25];
$output .= " 
<tr>
<td> <a href=\"download.php?dow=$cv\">Download</a> </td> 
</tr> 
";  
?>
```

the `\` before `"` called escaping and is needed because we dont want to end our  string! just want to add that quote sign as a character like the others.

Comment: It would have worked to just change the outer quotes to double quotes and keep the single quotes for the href-tag. Then there wouldn't be any need for escaping.

Comment: I do not know why, but when I click on Download now appears Error 403